# Windows 7 upgrade from OEM Vista - what info is needed?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, upgrade

I would like to upgrade to Windows 7 Home Premium.  I currently have a Dell PC that came pre-installed with Vista Home Premium on it.  I can't remember if the PC came with a Vista CD or not (I think nowadays Dell just offers the factory restore option from a hidden partition), but if it did come with a CD I'd rather not try and find it.

My question is do I need to have the Vista CD in order to successfully use the Windows 7 Home Premium upgrade?  Or, if not, what info do I need to have ready in order for the upgrade to work?  I don't want to purchase Windows 7 upgrade version only to find out that I need some piece of info that I don't have.

Thanks,

~ Justin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've upgraded working Vista machines to 7 several times now and never required the Vista DVD.

Make a backup, and ensure System Restore is turned on as well.

Ensure you have all your Windows 7 drivers collected ahead of time.

Run the [Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1B544E90-7659-4BD9-9E51-2497C146AF15&displaylang=en) to help identify potential problems.

Uninstall any hardware related *applications* (ie: scanning packages, printer utilities) that have a new Windows 7 version.  Since you'll have to probably have to replace them anyway if you uninstall them first the upgrade will go quicker/smoother.

Also, remember to uninstall any Anti-virus/security packages.

Don't be surprised if it takes 2-3 hours or more for the actual upgrade. :)